# SQL Server syntax error Msg:156, Level:15, State:1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to alter the following stored procedure, but I am getting a syntax error when I try to alter the procedure.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'. (Line 24)

Initially, I was executing the `InsLoginAttempts` incorrectly, but I corrected that.

Microsoft language reference doesn't seem to be any help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LogInUser
    (@UserID varchar(50),
     @Password varchar(15)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @UserExists varchar(50)
    SET @UserExists = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)

    DECLARE @CheckPassword varchar(15)
    SET @CheckPassword = (SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)

BEGIN
    IF @UserExists IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        IF @Password = @CheckPassword
            SELECT 'True' AS LoggedIn;

        EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Success';

        ELSE
            SELECT 'False' AS LoggedIn;

        EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Failed password attempt';
    END
    ELSE 
        SELECT 'False' AS LoggedIn;

    EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Failed username and password attempt';
    END
END
GO
```

It's obviously a syntax error, but where is it?

EDIT: Also, I don't know if it's worth noting or not, but I'm also using a client called SQLPro for SQL Server.

Comment: You should add BEGIN / END for the inner IF and ELSE as its content has more than one instructions

Comment: And same for your outer ELSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script are missing a BEGIN and END

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LogInUser(
    @UserID varchar(50),
    @Password varchar(15)
 )
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @UserExists varchar(50)
SET @UserExists = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)

DECLARE @CheckPassword varchar(15)
SET @CheckPassword = (SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID)

BEGIN
    IF @UserExists IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            IF @Password = @CheckPassword
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'True' AS LoggedIn;
                EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Success';
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SELECT 'False' AS LoggedIn;
                EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Failed password attempt';
            END
        END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'False' AS LoggedIn;
        EXEC InsLoginAttempts @SPUserID = @UserID, @SPPassword = @Password, @Comment = 'Failed username and password attempt';
    END

GO
```